# Opportunity Product Lookup Field Not Displaying Unedited Opportunity Line Items

Tags: lookup, opportunity-lineitem

I have an Opportunity Product/Opportunity Line Item lookup-relationship on a custom object in my development sandbox. The custom object also has a lookup relationship to an Opportunity. When I try to select an Opportunity Product relationship, I only see a subset of the available Opportunity Products in the select options. Newly-created Opportunity Products which have not been edited are not visible. If I navigate back to the newly-created Opportunity Product which I want to establish a relationship to, change any field, save, and then return to my custom object, that Opportunity Product is now visible. The relationship field on the custom object is editable for all profiles and visible to all on the page layout.

What appears to be happening is that Opportunity Products are invisible to lookup relationships if the created and last modified datetime stamps are ~equal.

As I don't want to have to advise users to edit all of their Opportunity Products, I'm hoping there's some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

I received a response from Salesforce support about this issue. The Opportunity Product lookup displays recently viewed records only. The following two workarounds for newly created Opportunity Product records will allow users to see and select them in the lookup field:

1. After creating a new Opportunity Product via the Opportunity record page, choose "view all" to see all of the Opportunity Products in the related list and then select the Opportunity Product that was just created. It will now be visible in the lookup field.
2. Take note of the Opportunity name when creating the new Opportunity Product and enter the Opportunity name in the Opportunity Product search field from the Opportunity Product lookup to see all Opportunity Products for that Opportunity.

Including recently created records in the recently viewed list on the Opportunity Product lookup would be a better solution. My experience has been that end-users were flummoxed when they couldn't see an Opportunity Product that they had just created in the Opportunity Product lookup field.